# ITaskScheduler::Delete fails

Tags: scheduled-tasks, nsis

```
!define GUIDTaskScheduler "{148BD52A-A2AB-11CE-B11F-00AA00530503}"
!define GUIDITaskScheduler "{148BD527-A2AB-11CE-B11F-00AA00530503}" 

Function DeleteTask
    !define DeleteTask "!insertmacro  _DeleteTask"
    !macro _DeleteTask _TASK _RESULT
        Push ${_Task}
        Call DeleteTask 
        Pop ${_RESULT}
    !macroend
    Exch $0
    Push $1
    Push $2
    StrCpy $0 false 
    System::Call "ole32::CoCreateInstance(g'${GUIDTaskScheduler}',i0,i11,g '${GUIDITaskScheduler}',*i.r1)i.r2"
    IntCmp $2 0 0 +4
    System::Call '$1->7(w r0)i.r2'
    IntCmp $2 0 0 +2
    StrCpy $0 true   
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    END:
    Exch $0
FunctionEnd

${DeleteTask} "TaskName" $0
Pop $0
```

$0 should set to true or 1 but it's false. The task isn't deleting.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: And what is the error code in $2?

Comment: I believe it's supposed to be set to 0 and 1 if an error is thrown. I'm fairly new still.

Comment: I've managed to get the problem taken care of by using boring ol' schtasks cmdline. However, this will bother me to no end until I've figured what's wrong..

Comment: Believing is pointless when you could just MessageBox $2 and find out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. This was bothering me to no end but I've managed to figure it out after rewriting it. Here's the working function.

```
Function DeleteTask
    !define TaskGUID    `{148BD52A-A2AB-11CE-B11F-00AA00530503}`
    !define ITaskGUID   `{148BD527-A2AB-11CE-B11F-00AA00530503}`
    !define OLE         `ole32::CoCreateInstance(g"${TaskGUID}",`
    !define OLE32       `${OLE}i0,i11,g "${ITaskGUID}",*i.r1)i.r2`
    !define DeleteTask "!insertmacro _DeleteTask"
    !macro _DeleteTask _RESULT _TASK
        Push ${_Task}
        Call DeleteTask 
        Pop ${_RESULT}
    !macroend
    Exch $0
    Push $0
    Push $1
    Push $2
    Push $3
    StrCpy $3 false
    System::Call `${OLE32}`
    IntCmp $2 0 0 +5
    System::Call "$1->7(w r0)i.r2"
    IntCmp $2 0 0 +3
    System::Call "$1->2()"
    StrCpy $3 true
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Pop $0
    Exch $3
FunctionEnd

;= $0 Should return either true on success or false on failure.
${DeleteTask} $0 "Task Name" 
StrCmpS $0 true 0 +2
DetailPrint "${TASK} was successfully deleted."
DetailPrint "Failed to remove the task ${TASK}."
```

Thanks goes to Anders for his help.

Answer (score 1):

Printing out the HRESULT error would probably give you a clue.

It looks like you are overwriting the service name with `StrCpy $0 false`!

You should also release the interface in $1 after you are done with it.

```
!define GUIDTaskScheduler "{148BD52A-A2AB-11CE-B11F-00AA00530503}"
!define GUIDITaskScheduler "{148BD527-A2AB-11CE-B11F-00AA00530503}" 

Function DeleteTask
!define DeleteTask "!insertmacro _DeleteTask"
!macro _DeleteTask _TASK _RESULT
    Push ${_Task}
    Call DeleteTask 
    Pop ${_RESULT}
!macroend
    Exch $0
    Push $1
    Push $2
    System::Call "ole32::CoCreateInstance(g'${GUIDTaskScheduler}',i0,i11,g '${GUIDITaskScheduler}',*i.r1)i.r2"
    IntCmp $2 0 "" fail
    System::Call '$1->7(w r0)i.r2' ; Delete($0)
    System::Call '$1->2()' ; Release
    fail:
    StrCpy $0 $2 ; HRESULT
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Exch $0
FunctionEnd

Section
${DeleteTask} "TaskName" $0
DetailPrint HRESULT=$0
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Didn't work.. `HRESULT = -21457464`. not exactly that number but it was similar to that but start with -2???? I see your point about unloading it so thanks for that one. Do we need to end a task before remove it or is there a force parameter?

Comment: You probably need to elevate with UAC. Try stopping the task if it is running. You need to tell us the exact error code!

Comment: Anders, I apologize for wasting your time. It's terrible how a simple mistake like forgetting to require administrative privileges can ruin an evening with debugging for hours.